# How to calcuate the time spent on status field on case when status="InProgess"

Tags: trigger

```
trigger CaseTrack on Case (after insert, after update) {
  List<Case> lstcse= New List<Case>();

  for (Case  case: Trigger.new) {  
    if (caseObj.Status== 'Inprogress'&& trigger.oldMap.get(caseObj.id).Status != 'Inprogress' ) {
      Case  obj = new Case ();
      obj.Date1__c = case.CreatedDate;
      obj.Date2__c = case.LastModifiedDate;
      lstcase.add(obj);
    }
  }

  update  lstcse; 
}
```

Comment: Can't you do that using a `Formula field of type Number` and just keep the number of day's it took to change the `Status = Inprogress`

Answer (score 0):

**Using Trigger:** Consider If you have a `custom field(NumberOfDaysForInProgress__c)` where you store the number of days it took for Inprogress status then try to use below code

```
trigger CaseTrack on Case (after insert, after update) {

      List<Case> lstcse= New List<Case>();

      for (Case  case: Trigger.new) {  

          if (caseObj.Status== 'Inprogress'&& trigger.oldMap.get(caseObj.id).Status != 'Inprogress' ) {
             Case  obj = new Case ();
             //obj.Date1__c = case.CreatedDate;
             //obj.Date2__c = case.LastModifiedDate;
             Datetime startDate = case.CreatedDate;
             Datetime endDate = case.LastModifiedDate;//system.now();
             //Take the number of days difference between the Created Date and Sytem.now / lastModifiedDate
             integer intDays =  startDate.Date().daysBetween(endDate.Date());
             obj.NumberOfDaysForInProgress__c = intDays;
             lstcase.add(obj);
          }
       } 
       update  lstcse; 
}
```

**Using Formula field**

```
(IF(ISPICKVAL(Status,"Inprogress"),Datevalue(LastModifiedDate)-Datevalue(CreatedDate),TODAY() - datevalue(CreatedDate)))
```